# manipulate dynamic input with php mysql and js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I have a table named description:

```
CREATE TABLE description(
  word_id int(11),
  word varchar (50),
  PRIMARY KEY (word_id)
);
```

and I try to get all word in this table and for every word I create a checkbox with value and id equal at a value of the word that I get from table description, 
 if the checkbox is checked, I save his value in var abcd.

```
<?php
///connection
$get_word = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM description");
while ($donnees = $get_word->fetch()) {
?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?php $donnees["word"] ?>" value="<?php $donnees["word"] ?>">
    <br>

    <script>
    $('#<?php $donnees["word"] ?>').on('change', function() {
        var abcd= this.checked ? this.value : '';
    });
    </script> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Now, I want to create a button out of boocle while , if this button is clicked,it must give me the value of checkbox checked.

Comment: You can do this simple form with input name

Comment: can you give me an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it using jQuery. As you already have the PHP logic, my example demonstrates the jQuery code only:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $("#getCheckedBoxes").on('click', () => {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, el){
        if($(el).is(':checked'))
          console.log($(el).val())
      })
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="Item 1">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" value="Item 2">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" value="Item 3">Item 3
<button id="getCheckedBoxes">Get checked boxes</button>
```

Comment: if checkbox are cereated dynamically  inside boocle while, and i want get the value of checkbox  checked       if i click a button created out of boocle while.

Comment: @user3623368, so you need to know which checkboxes had been checked by the user when this button is clicked, right?

Answer (score 0):

hope this will solve your problem

**PHP code**

```
<?php
///connection
  $get_word=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM description");
 while ($donnees = $get_word->fetch()) {
 ?>
<input type="checkbox" id="myid_<?php $donnees["word"] ?>" onclick="myfunc(<?php $donnees["word"] ?>)" value="<?php $donnees["word"] ?>"><br> 
 <?php
 }
?>
```

**JS CODE**

```
<script>
function myfunc(word){
  if(document.getElementById('myid_'+word).checked == true){
   var check_val = document.getElementById('myid_'+word).value;
   alert(check_val);
  }
}
</script>
```

or you can do this

```
<script>
function myfunc(word){
  if(document.getElementById('myid_'+word).checked == true){
   alert(word);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add class name such as `clickable` to your input tag.
after all rendering in php add script that runs when any input with clickable class changed and you can get that tag!

```php
<?php
$get_word=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM description");
while ($donnees = $get_word->fetch()) { ?>
<input class="clickable" type="checkbox" id="<?php $donnees["word"] ?>" value="<?php $donnees["word"] ?>">
<?php } ?>

<script>
$('.clickable').on('change', function(item) {
    console.log(item)
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that the OP can learn from your code. "Try this" is not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

I try this

```
///connection
    $get_word=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM description");
     while ($donnees = $get_word->fetch()) {
     ?>
     <label><?php echo $donnees["word"] ?></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myid_<?php $donnees["word"] ?>" onclick="myfunc(<?php $donnees["word"] ?>)" value="<?php $donnees["word"] ?>"><br>
     <?php
     }

    ?>
    <button id="getCheckedBoxes">Get checked boxes</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        'use strict';
        $("#getCheckedBoxes").on('click', () => {
          $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, el){
            if($(el).is(':checked'))
     alert($(el).val())   ;  
      })
        })
    })
    </script>
```

And the alert message is empty,it don't show the value of checkbox chekced